# A dwarven Path of the Ancestral Guardian, good builds/tips?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, balance, barbarian, dwarf

Recently I finished playing a character of mine in a long-running D&D campaign. My DM and I both decided it'd be best to leave my character behind because his story was finished and there was no reason for him to stay any longer.

The thing I'm having a problem with is creating a (level 12) barbarian. 
I've never played barbarian before but it seemed like a lot of fun to me! Path of the Ancestral Guardian especially spoke to me because the idea behind it is just so cool and I like being able to help my team whilst also doing damage and being able to soak it myself. The reason I *really* want to play a dwarf is that my party recently saved a group of dwarves from an erupting volcano (which turned out to be a monster), and I want to make a character who is thankful to them and wants to offer them his services in return.

Do any of you have any tips for me on creating such a character? What skills are important for me and which things are better to leave for other characters?

Here's a list of my party members at this moment:

- A Chronomancer Wizzard, a very smart character who focusses on utility spellcasting/crowd control and intelligence.
- A Phoenix Sorcerer, an incredible fire-themed sorcerer who focusses on charisma and blasting our enemies to pieces
- An Oath of Conquest Paladin, a dickhead paladin who deals amazing melee damage and also currently the tank of our team
- A Circle of the Shepherd Druid, a weird but friendly guy who focusses on survival/healing and action economy. This guy also has an awakened bear, a totem of the bear "barbarian". This bear is mainly focussed on protecting the druid though, so there is no need to take him into consideration.
- A Pact of the Undying Warlock, an edgy but loveable character focussing on AoE, necrotic damage, and summonings.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Welcome to our stack! Please take the [tour] to learn more about us and you can visit the [help] for more information.

Comment: We differ from forums in that we aren't really a discussion board, but Q&A resource. As it stands, your question is a prompt for discussion and doesn't really state what your character goals are for the build. DO you want the highest damage? Do you want to be able to 'tank'  and soak hits? Do you have another goal?